# Javascript - Add comma between date and time format

Tags: javascript, date, date-formatting

I'm trying to add a string comma (,) between the date and time formats. Can someone kindly show how I can achieve this for the following code? I thought it might be as simple as adding a comma in between, but unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working for me.

Example:
14 JUN 21, 18:55:03

Line 1:
`return handleFileType(req, res, user, dataFile, email, origin, previewSubject, finalFormatDate.format('DD MMM YY HH:mm:ss')`

Line 2:
`const date = moment.unix(dateToUnixTimestamp(memo.createdAt)).format('DD MMM YY HH:mm:ss');`

The reason I published both these lines, is because I'm not sure if anything can vary between them.

Comment: Just add comma in `format('DD MMM YY, HH:mm:ss')`

Comment: `.format('YY MMM DD, HH:MM:SS')` should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `format` method parses a format string and replaces tokens with values from the date. Non–tokens are kept as–is, so just add the comma where you want it in the format string:

```
format('DD MMM YY, HH:mm:ss')
```

```js
let date1 = moment().format('DD MMM YY HH:mm:ss');
console.log(date1)

let date2 = moment().format('DD MMM YY, HH:mm:ss');
console.log(date2)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

If you prefer to avoid using moment.js, it is also possible with native [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) javascript class methods:

```js
let a = new Date();

let timeStr = a.toLocaleTimeString('en-GB')
let dateStr = a.toLocaleDateString('en-GB')

let timeDateStr = dateStr + ', ' + timeStr;
console.log(timeDateStr);
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to do this without the `moment.js` dependency?